# Why has my question on a 4 day working week been closed down as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

As I noted in my question a 4 day working week has completed a 2 year trial run in Iceland and one is now being trialed in the UK.

This is eminently a political question so why has it been closed as being off-topic on a stack devoted to politics?

[Can a 4 day working week work in the USA?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/75614/can-a-4-day-working-week-work-in-the-usa)

Answer (score 8):

In the (likely) case the Q gets deleted, it asked:

> what I want to ask would a four day workimg week work in the USA? Or are people there married to their jobs there rather than their wives - it never seems like that in American sitcoms - it looks like they always have all the time in the world! I mean, see Friends!

I voted to close it as a poorly focused question that appears to be mostly an invitation for answers to chime in with personal opinions (and from an unclear perspective), rather than something based on facts. Esp. considering that it seems predicated on the opinionated sub-question "are people [in the US] married to their jobs there rather than their wives?" That impression (that you're soliciting opinions) was further reinforced by some of your comments under the Q:

> I'm more interested in what Americans have got to say about the concept. Its not right now abpit details.

This [answer](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6349/18373) in re "not a discussion forum" to a fairly similar issue is also relevant.

And I'm somewhat aware that such discussions on this topic [are present in some US media](https://www.npr.org/2022/07/06/1109316972/more-companies-are-trying-out-the-4-day-workweek-but-it-might-not-be-for-everyon), but I don't see in that [long] piece any mention of law initiatives etc. So you'd have to make some effort to explain how that's on-topic here, as opposed to [micro]economics SE. But as as formulated by you the Q seems geared to solicit pub-level banter/opinions on one side vs the other.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't vote to close, but was half thinking about it.  This passage

> Or are people there married to their jobs there rather than their wives

indicates that the main thrust of the question is not about the governments or how it works but about social norms.

So it may or may not be a question about the government.  It can be answered by ignoring that passage though, so it *can* be answered with just information about the relationship between the government and its employees as well as the government and the private sector employers.

Comment: That was simply rhetoric. The point is that to establish new working norms for an entire political economy will require the participation of central and local government. This is as much admitted for free market advocates sbo know full well laissez-fair policies are centrally and locally enforced.

Comment: @MoziburUllah if the question was rhetorical, then it is indeed off topic.  You may think that a person should naturally understand that you meant one part as the emphasis of the question and another part as playful commentary, but there is no guarantee that someone spending 20 seconds to read would get the same impression.  The site is not meant for banter.  Your comment shows that closing the question as "off topic" was actually appropriate.  The good news is that you can edit the question and make it on topic by removing the banter.

Answer (score -1):

The question was closed because it is about work policies and decisions that are up to businesses to make. This isn't something that the government would get involved in unless it was making a policy like they did with the 5 day/40 hour work week.

If a business wants to or doesn't want to implement a 4 day work week the government won't care about it or have any involvement in it.

Comment: The trial run in Iceland involved both local and central government.

Comment: @MoziburUllah As I stated in my comments on your question just because one government picked it up as an issue doesn't mean the entire topic is a government issue. If you had edited your question to include why the government would be looking at and what they would be doing it would be more on topic. But as it stands there is no reason for the government to get involved with trying a 4 day work week.

Comment: No, you are wrong. Government as the legislative  body must play a role if a four day working day is to come to pass. A level playing field would have to be enforced. This is acknowledged in the theory of free markets where the government backs the laws underlying a free market.

Comment: @JoeW this can be done by law (at least it is in some countries).  Whether or not the US government has such authority is a subject that can be discussed in an answer.

Comment: @wrod Yes, it can be done by law just as the current 5 day/40 hour work week is enforced by law. The problem being that the question isn't asking about what the government can do to change to a 4 day work week but about business in general shifting to a 4 day work week which requires nothing from the government to do. I suggested some changes to the question that would have made it on topic but it seems the poster didn't want to change it.